# Build multiple independent projects in the same solution in TeamCity

Tags: nuget-package, build-server, teamcity-9.0

I have an MVC app in VS2013, and it has several related web/service projects, and one console app that is used for running SQL scripts against the database (it uses DbUP, to integrate with Octopus Deploy).

How can I generate NuGet Packages for both the web app and the console app?
I have created a separate Visual Studio (sln) step to build this project, but I get a missing reference error for the DbUp NuGet package. If I add a project reference to the web app, then the build is successful, but no artifact is generated. I would like to generate the NuGet package without adding the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing. Adding OctoPack NuGet package to my console app solved my problems.